# how to specify the node's telemetry name for the relay chain when running a parachain node

Tags: parachain, cumulus

when running a parachain, we can specify arguments for the relay chain, by adding a double-dash (`--`) separator between parachain and relay chain arguments, like so:

```
$ calamari \
    --name ' marmara' \
    --base-path /var/lib/substrate \
    ...
    -- \
    --name ' marmara' \
    --telemetry-url 'wss://api.telemetry.manta.systems/submit/ 0' \
    ...
```

i have noticed that the `--name` parameter is always ignored when it appears in the relay chain arguments. this means that the node's relay-chain *telemetry name* is always set to a random name, which makes it difficult to identify a node quickly in a telemetry ui (eg: [here](https://telemetry.manta.systems/#list/0xb0a8d493285c2df73290dfb7e61f870f17b41801197a149ca93654499ea3dafe)).

is it possible to set the node's relay-chain *telemetry name* either with a different argument or by modifying the parachain node binary source code to honour the `--name` parameter? it seems the parameter is just ignored (without error or warning). at least in my testing with manta/calamari and moonbeam/moonriver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are specifying it is correct but indeed it was being ignored and a random name was used instead. This was just fixed yesterday: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1008.

Comment: oh, awesome. this is going to be rather useful.